# AngularJS select option text

Tags: angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I have a form for updating my pages. A Page has its parent page and I want to have a combobox where I can choose another parent page for my current Page. When the page is loaded I don't see the title of the current page's parent in the combobox. When I open the combobox I can see all the titles of all the pages.

**`Page.java`**

```
public class Page {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Page parentPage;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parentPage")
    private List<Page> childPages;

    /* other fields, constructors, getters and setters for all the fields... */
}
```

**`editPage.html`**

```
<div ng-controller="EditPageController">
  <form>
    ...
    <label>Parent page: </label>
    <select ng-model="currentPage.parentPage" ng-options="page.title for page in allPages"></select>
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

**`edit-page-controller.js`**

```
app.controller('EditPageController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PageService',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, PageService) {
        var pageId = $routeParams.pageId;
        PageService.getPageById(pageId, function (response) {
            $scope.currentPage = response.data;
            console.dir($scope.currentPage);
        });

        PageService.getAllPages(function (response) {
            $scope.allPages = response.data;
            console.dir($scope.allPages);
        });
        ...
    }
]);
```

My method `getPageById` is correctly fetching the page and `getAllPages` is correctly returning all existing pages as I can see in the console. What should I do so I can see the title of my current parent in the combobox?

Comment: Not clear if you mean that the option doesn't exist or that it exists and simply isn't selected

Comment: @charlietfl The option exists. For example, if my current page's parent is Page 10, in the database I have parent_page_id=10 and there really is a page with id=10, and of course with some meaningful title. Also, when I open the dropdown list I can see the Page 10 in the list, but it is not pre-selected when I start editing my current page.

Comment: Provide a sample of what `$scope.currentPage` and `$scope.allPages` look like. Either need to set `$scope.currentPage = response.data.title` or find the matching object in `$scope.allPages` as the object references are different but approach depends a bit on data structure. Or using `track by` might help

Comment: This example might help https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/o4RJ2N

Comment: @charlietfl That's it, "track by" helped. Thanks :)

Comment: @charlietfl If you want you can write an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks once more :)